# Refactoring long if/else if statement with for loop - javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know there is a way for me to refactor this code, but I can't figure it out and I could use some help. I created a tic tac toe game and created the functionality to declare a winner, it works, but it's way too long.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var turn = 0;
    // var winOptions = [['#1','#2','#3'], ['#4','#5','#6'], ['#7','#8','#9'], [1,5,9], [3,5,7], [1,4,7], [3,6,9], [2,4,8]];

    $('td').on("click", function() {
        if (turn % 2 === 0) {
            $(this).text("0");
        } else {
            $(this).text("X");
        }
        $(this).off("click");
        turn++;
        checkForWinner()
    });


    function checkForWinner() {
        if ($('#1').text()==='X' && $('#2').text()==='X' && $('#3').text()==='X')
            alert('you win!');
        else if ($('#4').text()==='X' && $('#5').text()==='X' && $('#6').text()==='X')
            alert('you win!');
        else if ($('#7').text()==='X' && $('#8').text()==='X' && $('#9').text()==='X')
            alert('you win!');
        else if ($('#1').text()==='X' && $('#5').text()==='X' && $('#9').text()==='X')
            alert('you win!');
        else if ($('#3').text()==='X' && $('#5').text()==='X' && $('#7').text()==='X')
            alert('you win!');
        else if ($('#1').text()==='X' && $('#4').text()==='X' && $('#7').text()==='X')
            alert('you win!');
        else if ($('#3').text()==='X' && $('#6').text()==='X' && $('#9').text()==='X')
            alert('you win!');
        else if ($('#2').text()==='X' && $('#4').text()==='X' && $('#8').text()==='X')
            alert('you win!');
        else if ($('#1').text()==='O' && $('#2').text()==='O' && $('#3').text()==='O')
            alert('you win!');
        else if ($('#4').text()==='O' && $('#5').text()==='O' && $('#6').text()==='O')
            alert('you win!');
        else if ($('#7').text()==='O' && $('#8').text()==='O' && $('#9').text()==='O')
            alert('you win!');
        else if ($('#1').text()==='O' && $('#5').text()==='O' && $('#9').text()==='O')
            alert('you win!');
        else if ($('#3').text()==='O' && $('#5').text()==='O' && $('#7').text()==='O')
            alert('you win!');
        else if ($('#1').text()==='O' && $('#4').text()==='O' && $('#7').text()==='O')
            alert('you win!');
        else if ($('#3').text()==='O' && $('#6').text()==='O' && $('#9').text()==='O')
            alert('you win!');
        else if ($('#2').text()==='O' && $('#4').text()==='O' && $('#8').text()==='O')
            alert('you win!');
        }
});
```

I started making the array variable win options to loop through, but it still isn't working.

FYI, those selectors are the id's for each td tag in my HTML.

Thanks for taking a look at this.

Comment: Add HTML too, it'll be better to see HTML

Comment: This would be so much easier if you'd save your board state into a 2D array as well, instead of checking the DOM every time. Then it just becomes a simple reduction.

Comment: Just a side note: `#5` and such are invalid CSS selectors. jQuery lets you *get away* with them, in isolation, as a by-product of the fact it optimizes them into calls to `getElementById`, but that's purely a by-product of an optimization (and so, in theory, could stop happening between one dot rev and the next), and they fail for (say) `$("#5 span")`. A CSS ID selector cannot start with an unescaped digit. `#1` is properly written `#\31`, which of course in a string would have to be `"#\\31"`. Moral: If you plan to use them with CSS selectors, don't start IDs with digits. :-)

Comment: This question might be more appropriate on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Kristján I was unaware of codereview. Thanks for bringing that to my attention.

Answer (score 1):

Some refactoring along the lines of Shilly's comment might be called for. However, without drastically changing your design, you could do something like the following:

```
var winConditions = [
   ['#1','#2','#3'], ['#4','#5','#6'], ['#7','#8','#9'], // rows
   ['#1','#4','#7'], ['#2','#5','#8'], ['#3','#6','#9'], // columns
   ['#1','#5','#9'], ['#3','#5','#7']                    // diagonals
];

for (var i = 0, len = winConditions.length; i < len; i++) {
  var text = $(winConditions[i][0]).text();
  if (
    (text === 'X' || text === 'O') && 
    $(winConditions[i][1]).text() === text && $(winConditions[i][2]).text() === text
  ) {
    alert('you win!');
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Cool! I didn't  know that you can check multiple conditions (a == b == c) in the same JavaScript condition without &&ing them (a == b && b == c) like in Python. Is that supported by all browsers?

Comment: @AidasBendoraitis, actually, I'm not sure that it is. I've edited my answer. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: I tested the multiple conditions in Chrome's console. It works! :)

Comment: @AidasBendoraitis, that's weird, for me, `if (1 === 1 === 1) { 'hi'; }` yielded `undefined`, but `if (1 === 1) { 'hi'; }` yielded `"hi"`. This was in Chrome.

Comment: Oh. Now I see. The 1 === 1 returns true and then true is compared with 1 which is false.
That makes this valid: 4 < 5 < 3, where true (or 1) is less than 3.

So multiple conditions don't work in JavaScript as in Python.